# Force SSL just for a specific page

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

Right now the whole site is configured to use SSL in Apache, but I would like to use SSL just for a specific page. Let's say:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/purchase/buy/28
```

So everything inside `purchase/` (buy, cancel, check, whatever) must be encrypted. What are the Apache and [mod_rewrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) rules to accomplish that?

I have tried with:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mydomain.com/city/ [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But had no luck :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} purchase
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/purchase/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally we used:  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} purchase
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

Comment: Please note that you could change `^(.*)$` to **`(.*)`** (FMHPOV it's cleaner)

Comment: Appreciated and true, though I personally prefer the explicit start and end tokens and find them *clearer* - explicit vs cleaner I will personally always go with explicit, especially when I am not trying to conserve file size (in Javascript, for instance, cleaner might win to reduce transport time)